# How to group records by a field in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've got a MongoDB document which has records that looks like this:

```
[
  { _id: id, category_name: 'category1', parent_category: null },
  { _id: id, category_name: 'category2', parent_category: null },
  { _id: id, category_name: 'subcategory1', parent_category: id_parent_1 },
  { _id: id, category_name: 'subcategory2', parent_category: id_parent_1 },
  { _id: id, category_name: 'subcategory3', parent_category: id_parent_2 },
  { _id: id, category_name: 'subcategory4', parent_category: id_parent_2 }
]
```

As you can see, I'm storing categories with a `parent_category` of `null`, and subcategories have the parent category's ID. What I'm looking for is to group these into some kind of format like this:

```
[
  { category_name: 'category1', categories: [
       { category_name: 'subcategory1', _id: id },
       { category_name: 'subcategory2', _id: id }
    ]
  },
  { category_name: 'category2', categories: [
       { category_name: 'subcategory3', _id: id },
       { category_name: 'subcategory4', _id: id }
    ]
  }
]
```

So basically group the parent categories with an array with their child categories. I'm using Mongoose. I tried using the aggregation framework MongoDB provides but I can't get the desired result. :(

I have access to modify the schema in any way that could be needed!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you designed your document that way at first place? maybe you can redesign you mongoose schemma and make some methods to validate the parent_id to assign the subcategories

Comment: Is it just two levels of categories? can your subcategories have their own subcategories?

Comment: @JoseOsorio I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: @yarons yes, it'll be just two levels, category and subcategory

Comment: Look at this category tree library for mongoose: https://github.com/incrediblesound/category-tree . Here a blog post from the author: http://incrediblesound.github.io/blog/2014/07/27/how-to-integrate-an-app-with-mongoose/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're treating Mongo like an relational database (separating all these fields and bringing them together with a query). What you should do is rebuild your Schema. For example:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
   category_name: String,
   subCategories:[subCategorySchema]
}

var subCategorySchema = new Schema({
   category_name: String
})
```

This way when you need to query the collection it's a simple

```
db.find({category_name: "name of the category"}, function(){})
```

to get everything you need.

Just in case: you can add the sub categories to the array with simple updates. Read [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update-array/) for more info.

Comment: Had to modify this a little bit to suit my needs but overall it was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if Your schema is not changed:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

//connect away
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to Database");

  //simple json record
    var document = [];
    //insert record
    //db.data.find({"parent_category":null }).forEach(function(data) {print("user: " + db.data.findOne({"parent_category":data._id })) })
    db.collection('data').find({"parent_category":null }, function(err, parentrecords) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var cat ={};
        parentrecords.forEach(function(data){
            cat["category_name"] = data["category_name"];
            db.collection('data').find({"parent_category":data._id },function(err, childrecords) {
                var doc = [];
                childrecords.forEach(function(childdata){
                    doc.push(childdata);
                        },function(){
                        cat["categories"] = doc;
                        document.push(cat);
                        console.log(document);
                    });
            });
        });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out expected results without changing schema then you basically follow some complex mongo `aggregation` query. For finding output I follow following steps :

1. First in `$project` check `parent_category` equals `null` if true then add `_id` else add `parent_category`.
2. Now document structure looks like with new `key name as parent_id` presents and group by `parent_id` and push remaining data like `category_name and parent_category`.
3. After that use **[$setDifference](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[$setIntersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** to differentiate parent data and child data.
4. And in finally `unwind` only single array objects so this single array object and used project for showing only those fields which to display.

Check working aggregation query as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "parent_id": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": ["$parent_category", null]
                },
                "then": "$_id",
                "else": "$parent_category"
            }
        },
        "category_name": 1,
        "parent_category": 1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$parent_id",
        "categories": {
            "$push": {
                "category_name": "$category_name",
                "parent_category": "$parent_category"
            }
        },
        "parentData": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$parent_category", null]
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "category_name": "$category_name",
                        "parent_category": "$parent_category"
                    },
                    "else": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "findParent": {
            "$setIntersection": ["$categories", "$parentData"]
        },
        "categories": {
            "$setDifference": ["$categories", "$parentData"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$findParent"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "category_name": "$findParent.category_name",
        "categories": 1
    }
}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to group records by a field try using **$group** in **Aggreegation**.This worked for me.

**Example**

```
db.categories.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : {category_name:"$category_name"}, categories: { $push: {category_name:"$category_name",_id:"$_id"} } } }
   ]
)
```

**Reference**:
[MongoDB Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-title-by-author)

Hope this works.